# Do I have to use Azure SQL Easy Tables

Tags: sql, azure, xamarin

Using Xamarin, if you want to use Azure's `MobileServiceClient` class to talk to an `SQL database` stored on the `Azure Portal`, must you use Azure's `Easy Tables` software in the Azure Portal to initially set up your SQL tables, or can you create them independently (for example using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017) ?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you want to use Azure's MobileServiceClient class to talk to an SQL database stored on the Azure Portal, must you use Azure's Easy Tables software in the Azure Portal to initially set up your SQL tables

No, You could use your own database without using easy table.

I should firstly tell you the difference of the C# backend and Node.js backend.

Easy table is used in the Node.js bakcend.

If you create a Node.js backend, azure will auto create the Node.js backend without deploy.

It will auto bind the sql database table into easy table.

If you don't want to use easytable, you could use your own logic for mobile client to call it.

But if you use C# backend, azure will not bind the table to the easy table.

Because, the C# backend use EF codefirst to create table. If the request send to the backend, EF will auto create the table.

You could use azure mobile client library InvokeApiAsync method to directly call the backend method.

C# Code like this:

```
  public static async Task<string> GetApplicationToken()
    {
        var clientUri = $"https://your-mobile-app-id.azurewebsites.net";

        var client = new MobileServiceClient(clientUri);
        var response = await client.InvokeApiAsync<string>("/api/values", HttpMethod.Get, null);
        return response;
    }
```

---

> At the moment I have some Easy Tables for my SQL database, but I am in the process of moving my MySQL database over to Azure and would like to (if possible) import my tables through SQL server management studio 17 and then configure them to work with Easy Tables, is this possible, and practical?

If you use node.js backend, after you moving the data. You just need add the table name as below in the easy table.

[image]

If you use C# backend, after you moving the data. You should create your own class and inherit the EntityData class.

If you inherit the EntityData class, you could use multiple azure mobile server library method.

Like this:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

Comment: Great answer thank you. At the moment I have some Easy Tables for my SQL database, but I am in the process of moving my MySQL database over to Azure and would like to (if possible) import my tables through SQL server management studio 17 and then configure them to work with Easy Tables, is this possible, and *practical*?

Comment: Yes, you could move the data from the mysql to SQL database. After moving, if you use Node.js backend, you just need to add the table name in the easy table.Then you could use it. Make sure the table name must be same. If you use C# backend, you need create your own model according to your new added table. More details, you could see my update answer.

Comment: Hi Brando, thank you very much for your help, I have made another question regarding the transistion, would you mind taking a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711067/azure-data-not-showing-on-easy-tables

Comment: I'm so sorry that I'm not good at node.js. I found Arron has already answered your question.