# Azure - Data not showing on Easy Tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am using an Azure SQL back-end for my Xamarin mobile application. I am using Easy tables with Node.JS to handle my back-end. I have created a few tables using the easy tables creation wizard, but now I wish to manually migrate some of my old MySQL tables, such as my table named `users` from another database into my new Azure SQL database.

**1)** I have used the SqlMigration3 tool to convert the MySQL tables into Azure SQL, changed the schema to be the same as the Easy Table's schema, and they are now in my Azure SQL Database
[image]

**2)** I have created the Node.JS files `users.js` and `users.json` in my `App Service Editor` and now my table is showing in easy tables

**users.js**

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

// table.read(function (context) {
//     return context.execute();
// });

// table.read.use(customMiddleware, table.operation);
```

**users.json**

```
  {
  "softDelete" : true,
  "autoIncrement": false,
  "insert": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "update": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "delete": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "read": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  },
  "undelete": {
    "access": "anonymous"
  }}
```

The `users` table is showing up in Easy Tables **but** there is no data showing, despite the data displaying in SQL Server Management Studio 2017. Have I missed a step? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test, I am also unable to see the data from Azure portal when I do the same steps as yours. I think the portal needs time to load the data since it might have many records.

[image]

Since you set `Read permission` to `Allow anonymous access`, I would recommend accessing the table via REST API:

```
https://[YourAppName].azurewebsites.net/tables/users?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

[image]